# Custom form, shortcode, and submit handler

Tags: shortcode, forms, front-end

I have a frontend form with a bunch of input. My requirements force me to use a custom shortcode to create the form. I have already tested a page with that shortcode.

Here's my :

```
<form name="myform" method="post" action="<?php echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Based on this, it should open up the same page (and it did). However, when I hit submit, I got 404 on that very same URL. Is there any solution?

**UPDATE #1**

I try different route, using add_action('init'):

```
add_action('init', 'mbro1_intercept_form_input');
function mbro1_intercept_form_input()
{
    if( !(isset($_POST['action_code']) && $_POST['action_code'] == 'mbro_intercept_form_input') )
        return "";
    if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
    {
        //do my code here
        wp_redirect( get_permalink(35) );//page that has [shortcode]
    }
}
```

This successfully run my intended action on submit. But! upon redirection, it still got 404. I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Whats your form code?

Comment: @bainternet here: http://pastebin.com/fXvyuwnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take `die()` as solution. Though, I don't prefer this.

```
$redirect_link =  get_permalink(35) ; //page that has form
$script_redirect = "<div>Your form is submitted. Please wait a moment. If your browser didn't redirect, click <a href='$redirect_link'>here</a>.</div>
<script type='text/javasript' language='javascript'> 
    window.location = '$redirect_link';
</script> ";
die( $script_redirect );
```

Comment: Does it work if you add the `die()` after your call to `wp_redirect()`? Just calling the redirect does not stop script execution. You see this pattern in the core code too: `wp_redirect( $somewhere ); exit;`.

Comment: We'll somehow it work. I did try wp_redirect(); exit; Weird, right?

Answer (score 0):

Does your form have an input with the name "name"? For example:

```
<input type="text" name="name">
```

If so, that will cause trouble. Change the name value.

Also see: [Form 'name' breaks and goes to 404 page](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/form-name-breaks-and-goes-to-404-page).

Comment: I don't have 'name' on my form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the line near the end

`wp_redirect( get_permalink(35) );//page that has form`

is what is failing. I would change it to this

```
$redirect_link =  get_permalink(35) ; //page that has form
wp_redirect( $redirect_link );  // trigger redirect
exit;
```

that should cause it to function to work properly

Comment: it doesn't work either T_T

Comment: What is the 404 link, in specific? i.e. what's the URL of the page it's trying to redirect to and thus 404ing on?

Comment: it come from example.com/?page_id=35 and on submit, it goes to example.com/?page_id=35. After process, it should redirect to example.com/?page_id=35 so that when user hit refresh, it doesn't have any effect to site.

Comment: ups, wrong click. Well, it's your lucky day to get +50 reps ;))